# node.js readFile memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, memory-leaks

Im using node.js to read an image every second. The idea is to later push it to web browsers, making it a simple stream. The code looks as following:

```
var fs      = require("fs");
var intervalTimerObj;

function startStream() {
    if(!intervalTimerObj) {
        intervalTimerObj = setInterval( updateStream  , 1000);
    }
}

function updateStream(){
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/pic.jpg", function(err, image) {

    });
}

startStream();
```

When running the code above I seem to get a memory leak as my memory quickly fills up.
The larger the image file i load, the quicker it fills up.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some way to 'release' the image variable? I've tried nulling it.

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` update the stream when you finished reading an image on the `fs.readFile` callback. it's better to read an image and then if you really need that 1000ms interval to use `setTimeout` to start the next reading

Comment: Just tried to use setTimeout instead. Still keeps stealing all my memory

Comment: Why are you doing it every 1000ms, anyway?

Comment: The idea is to capture a picture each second and then pushing it to web browsers via socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better approach. `setInterval()` should not be used here because it could lead to simultaneous execution of the same task. Use `setTimeout()` instead. The ideal place to do it is inside `readFile()`'s callback:

```
var fs            = require("fs");
var timeoutHandle = null;

function startTimeout() {
  stopTimeout();
  timeoutHandle = setTimeout(updateStream, 1000);
}

function stopTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
}

function updateStream(){
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/pic.jpg", function(err, image) {
      // ...

      startTimeout(); // Make sure this line is always executed
    });
}

startTimeout();
```

You also need to make sure you don't mantain any reference to `image` after you process it, otherwise V8's garbage collector won't free the image data, thus leaking memory.

Comment: Im running your startTimeout function but still the memory is never released. Every time it loads an image my memory goes up. Do startTimeout work for you?

Comment: I've tested your solution for a long run and seems the memory usage stabilize on ~40%(200mb) memory usage. Is this to be expected? Thanks for the code btw!

Comment: Yes, it seems normal. You need to be very careful when working with large amounts of data inside loops. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function startStream() {
    if(!intervalTimerObj) {
        intervalTimerObj = setTimeout( updateStream  , 1000);
    }
}

function updateStream(){
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/pic.jpg", function(err, image) {
       //OK file is read
       //do yoyr stuff with it....
       // Now start next read
       startStream()
    });
}

startStream();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Still my memory goes up all the time though. I'm monitoring the ram with top command(using linux) and it never goes down.

Comment: My guess is you're entering in loop calls circle, somewhere. Check your code, debug if possible and think of a better pattern. If new issue come back post a question. This code is such pattern. 2 functions are calling each other